# How can I make the people at my company understand that learning a spoken and written language takes time?

Tags: work-environment, teamwork, language

I am working for an international company, yet on every meeting my colleagues and bosses are speaking German (as far as I know they all speak English).

It happened that someone wanted to respect me to speak English, then someone else spoke up and said 'She has to learn German'. The company does not support language learning, but I am taking private classes twice per week to get better. However, I feel pressured that they mention it often that I have to learn it, as am not at a level to speak comfortably yet. I can talk about easy topics, but am definitely not on a level that would benefit me at the workplace.

Now they asked me to do a presentation in German, which frustrates me and I don't know what to do. They know about my classes, but it feels they don't care. I don't want to seem weak, but I feel really uncomfortable about it and I don't know what to do. I am not sure how to get their respect or if I should look for another job.

---

**Wow, thank you everyone for taking the time to write such lengthy, helpful, and kind responses. Please excuse the time I have taken to answer your questions, I hope below I answer everything you were curious about and that it might clarify some of the assumptions as well.**

- The whole interview process, including a task I had to do were all in English. The base of the company is in Germany, however, we have partner companies in many other, foreign countries, including France, Italy, Spain, Malaysia, and the United Kingdom to just name a few.
- It was that I would be mainly working with our developers (they are mostly foreigners and the majority of them only speak English, their meetings are only held in English as well). But as I am a designer, they placed me in the Product Management team, where basically everyone is German, except me. I was upfront about my German skills from the beginning and it was said it is not a problem, as this is an international company and everyone should be able to speak English with me. However, every product meeting which is just as relevant to me is in German.
- It is important to mention that we are having a really complex product, so I would need to speak at least B2 or C1 level to understand them properly, which is even harder due to the different dialects.
- My contract does not mention anything about what is the official language at the company, nor that I am expected to speak German after a certain amount of time.
- The contract is in German, although other documents within the company are available in English and German, as well as often in Spanish, French, and Italian. (Due to partner companies).
- English is not my first language (apologies in case of any mistakes), so I know what it takes to learn a language and I know it is important to practice speaking. I believe I might not clarify it properly in my original post, but I am learning German and I can talk about easy topics, so in fact, I do use the language, but at this point not in the business environment. I believe I try my best to get better, despite the lack of support from the company. At this point, German-speaking colleagues have English classes offered by the company, but English speakers do not have German classes, so I believe demanding to speak German is not the right approach in this case, especially as I mentioned earlier, I was upfront about this and they hired me knowing about my lack of German knowledge. I myself decided to start taking classes privately. This means I pay for my courses and I use my free time to eventually benefit the company that I, as well, speak German.
- My problem with the statement “She has to learn German” was the disrespect. The person who held the meeting asked me if he should do the meeting in English and another person (my supervisor, a man) answered before I could do so, “No, she has to learn German”. This was followed by an awkward silence, then the meeting went on in German. It was an important meeting for me and I could not understand half of it, so I had to reach out to someone afterward to explain it to me. This took time and unnecessary effort, which could have been avoided if we just held the meeting in English in the first place. This was not the first time that this has happened.
- The presentation was required by my supervisor and another colleague from the product team (my manager was not there that time). They requested this 2 days before the presentation took place. If I had enough time I could have prepared and memorized a script in German, but due to the complexity of the topic, the time would not have been enough.
- I did the presentation in English and I scheduled a call with my manager to talk to him about my concerns. (He is also the manager of my supervisor.) I am not sure what to expect, but to be honest, at this point I feel I do not belong to this company. If there are other foreigners, everyone automatically switches to English, but if I am the only foreigner in the meeting, this is just simply not the case. Maybe they think they are helping as I mentioned I am taking German classes, but I feel this approach only holds me back from actually doing a good and efficient job.

Comment: Question: When you were hired, was the interview conducted in English or German? What is the location that you were hired in? What is/was the expectation given as to which Team/Management/Location you would be primarily working in/with?

As depending on those factors, it drastically changes the advice.

Comment: Also, what does your contract say? What did they say during the interview? What was written in the job description? Are you a full time employee located in Germany?

Comment: Are the official documents such as design documents, requirements, specifications for the projects written in English or German or both ?

Comment: It doesn’t matter what “the contract says” or what language the interview was in if the coworkers and management now want the OP to learn German. He is not going to be able to convince them or “force” them to speak English in their own country if they don’t want to.

Comment: @teego1967 Germany has much stronger labor laws than Pennsylvania does. And the OP referred to herself as "she".

Comment: In contrast to the US, which does not have an official language, German is the only official language throughout all states (some states have secondary official languages, but English is not one of them). So if the contract says nothing about language, a court would *probably* rule that OP needs to speak German.  Anyway, Germans tend to dislike people who live here and don't learn German (this is different from tourists), so learning the language is highly recommended. And 99% of the population will prefer an inadequate effort to "not even trying".

Comment: Is English your first language? Have you tried to learn any other foreign languages besides German?

Comment: *"Now they asked me to do a presentation in German"* Who's "they"? Your employer? Your boss? A colleague? Is the person who asked you to do the presentation the same person as the one who asked you to do it in German?

Comment: Lots of people in the comments are assuming the OP is working in Germany and that German is the expected language for all employees of the company. There's no mention of that in the question whatsoever.

Comment: "If there are other foreigners, everyone automatically switches to English, but if I am the only foreigner in the meeting, this is just simply not the case.". Are you really sure your the only one subjected to this treatment? Can you correlate the different treatment to your job position? Is there really no apparent logical or professional reason to treat you differently?

Comment: Just a little side fact: neutral/matter of fact statements in German often sound grumpy/negative to Foreigners not used to German. "She has to learn German" could have been simply a statement of facts and may have sounded to you like an offense.

Comment: Just make sure you don't use "it takes time" as an excuse to not learn the language as quickly as you can. If you need additional tutoring it's probably worth the investment if you expect to stay in the country. I still regret not having worked harder to build my Spanish skills before and during the 2 years they'd have been most useful; the folks I was working with all spoke excellent English and liked practicing it and I got lazy.

Answer (score 66):

It looks like your bosses believe in the [immersion approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_immersion) to language learning. It has been shown to be effective. I have worked with quite some people trying to learn German. Those not immersing themselves in the language were never really successful.

They know you are not perfect yet. They just have decided that immersing you in German is more important and an aceptable trade-off over you delivering you best work in English. Some of your colleagues might also not feel as comfortable speaking English as you believe.

If you want to work in Germany or Austria long-term, being able to speak German is important for your career. Their approach could help with that. So, I suggest you try it even if it stresses you out in the beginning. Obviously, you are going to make mistakes but they expect that.

Others have recommended to check if your contract requires you to speak German. Well, you should do that. But even if it is not in your contract, fighting this will hurt your career in this company and it is not unlikely that you will have similar issues in the next company if you stay in Germany or Austria.

Comment: This. They know that you're still learning. It's OK if you have to ask for folks to slow down, or to repeat something, or occasionally to translate something for you because you don't know the word or idiom.  But the only way you are going to develop something approaching fluency is to actually use the language. If it's going slower than you like, some additional time or money spent specifically on language study might be worth investing in... but it's unavoidable that you're going to feel like an idiot for a while. If your manager tells you not to worry, don't worry and keep trying.

Comment: I'm sure there's a learning-languages discussion somewhere on Stack Exchange or a similar site that can give you lots of good tips. For me, watching TV or listening to the radio was helpful in improving my listening comprehension in Spanish (I should be doing that more now, to recover that skill), and rereading some favorite books in translation helped with reading comprehension, though my ability to actually come up with the needed words to _speak_ it improved much more slowly. It could be worse; it could be a tonal language or one with a different writing system.

Comment: Honestly, I feel this answer is way too naive and ignores the context entirely. I 100% agree that immersion is the best way to learn a language (that's how I learnt English). However, the way they said `'She has to learn German'` and cut the other colleague off does not seem welcoming / kind. I've worked with several native asian / arabic colleagues, and while I encouraged them to speak French as much as possible, I had no issue switching back to English if they struggled with a sentence or technical context

Comment: @Aserre the way that phrase was said, nor the idea that anyone was cut off, is not present in the description of the situation. I don't think it's a good idea to imagine the situation and answer based on that - that assumption is what's naive.

Comment: @Aserre I am dutch, not german, but I would word a sentence in pretty much the same way. I think you are translating it as "you are commanded to learn english" and i would translate it as "it is necessary you learn english". I'd chalk this one up to cultural differences.

Comment: As someone who speaks pretty good English and has lots of non-native friends: It's no kindness to use English with friends and colleagues if they want to stay in Germany or Austria for longer. Yeah it's way more exhausting for everyone involved (it's vastly easier to just speak English with someone than trying to understand what they're saying and then speaking particularly slowly and clearly) but that's how people learn the language - by using it and their day to day life. 
I don't think I've ever met anyone who learned to speak German well by going to language courses a few time a week.

Comment: @Borgh You are spot on. I am Dutch too, English is the language I have used all my professional life and since a few years I work in Germany. I have been through the exact situation as described in the question. When someone said 'he has to learn German' about me, the English interpreter in me felt disrespected. And then I realised that Dutch and German subtleties do not always translate easily into English. It turned out that this was not disrespectful at all, it was an act of kindness. Offering a platform for me to practice my German, fully understanding that I would mess their language up.

Comment: This is the correct answer. And I say this as a foreigner living in Germany for more than 10 years. My work environment has always been in English, my german skills have always been lacking due to this. They are making OP a huge favour forcing the language on her.

Comment: I feel there are some problems with this answer wrt to the OP actual situation. I agree immersion is a very effective way to *learn* a language, but the problem here is that the OP is also required to carry out complex activities using German at B2 or C1 level *and* be productive as she does so (as I got it, she is not considered a trainee whose job is just support or collateral to another senior colleague's). Moreover the company doesn't seem to support her efforts, since German speakers were offered English courses, but she was not offered German courses.

Comment: And German has a very different learning curve than English: with the latter it's very easy to learn the basics (except pronunciation) and be productive. Conversely, German is very difficult for absolute beginners, and the OP is learning German through a third language (English) which it's not her own native one. Moreover technical/business English is quite easy to grasp compared to tech/business German. All-in-all it doesn't seem the company is really trying to help her.

Comment: In addition, they hired her *knowing* her German knowledge was null, and (IIUC) didn't tell her explicitly upfront she ***had to** learn German* at C1 level to fulfill her role. 
I agree that the OP would benefit greatly to learn German at the level required for her job, but this requires time and it's questionable whether her career would be impacted more by failures caused by her not being able to do her job (effectively) because she has had no time to learn the language. Immersion is not magic, you still need time to learn, and no degree of immersion could compensate for lack of time.

Comment: "Tough love", aka *immersion*, is indeed the only good answer. Otherwise, OP will have the exact same problem in 1, 5 or 10 years.

Comment: This is a bad answer. The choice on whether a certain language should be used in a certain context where only one person in the group is non-fluent comes down that person only. No "tough love". The OP is the one in charge of their learning and it is not up to anyone else to impose on that, given they were hired with the expectation of using English. This is a culture problem and if your company is not willing to treat this as an issue you should probably start searching for a new job.

Comment: @EricDuminil no, why? The OP is actively learning language. In 2 years she'll be B2/C1 depending, and will have no problem following the meetings in German. In the meantime, the company can just, well, keep to the agreement, and have her work in English. It will be more efficient and more beneficial for everyone.

Comment: @njzk2: I've been working for 15 years in Germany, with many foreigners. Some bite the bullets and become fluent really fast, and are thankful afterwards that colleagues regularly spoke German with them. Others, like OP, get offended easily, look for excuses and don't learn much German, if at all. Many years later, they still have the same problems, the same excuses, and still expect colleagues to make more effort than themselves. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EricDuminil I, by no means try to argue with you, but I feel you are missing the point of my original post. The company hired me knowing I do not speak German and English was the language we agreed upon.
I believe if this requirement has changed, they should discuss it with me before they try to impose it, while still expecting me to perform on a high level and deliver quality work. I am not sure why you think I am looking for excuses, when I decided myself to take German classes and learn in my free time.

Comment: @EricDuminil Furthermore, as I am constantly using English for main communication, which is actually not my mothertongue, I also do an effort to communicate with my colleagues. 
Assuming I will not be able to speak German just because I chose a different method to learn than you or some of your colleagues is, in my opinion, just simply wrong.

Answer (score 29):

I've been in a similar situation in Japanese (my second language) at a company I previously worked at.  You basically have 3 choices:

1. Get really good at German, really fast.  This is the most unrealistic one.  It takes time to get good at a language, and it takes confidence, neither of which you have.  Based on the grammatical errors in your question, I'm guessing English is not your first language either, and based on interactions with international people I have had, and basing off the sorts of grammar mistakes those people make, my guess is you are Chinese in origin (the grammatical errors in your question are most similar to the grammatical errors that Chinese speakers-of-English-as-a-second-language make).  I know it is very frowned upon in Chinese culture to look anything less than perfect, but the fact of the matter is that sometimes you have to look bad once in a while to improve your skill at something.  The more you speak German, and the more German is spoken around you, the better you will get at German.  You'll have to make yourself look like an idiot once or twice (or more...MUCH more...), but you'll have to put your pride aside and just do it, if you want to accelerate the rate at which you get good at German.
2. Inform your coworkers of why they should not speak to you in German.  This was the tactic I took when I was in Japan.  It was once written (I forgot who): If you want to convince someone to do something, you have to explain to them two things: "what's in it for me?", and "why do I care?".  Why do these people want to speak to you in English?  What advantage do they gain by speaking to you in English rather than their native German?  Simply put, the advantage they gain is that you are not good at German, so if they speak to you in German you may misunderstand them, which will impact your work and your productivity.  Getting better at German is one thing, and you are doing your best at that, but in the meantime, in order to communicate with you effectively, they should speak to you in English to make sure they are understood by you.
3. Quit your job.  If this company has a culture of speaking only in German, and you do not feel like you can accommodate that culture, then you should find a job at a company which is more English-friendly.  If you can't speak German (well), and your coworkers won't or can't accommodate speaking to you in English, then you're at an impasse; you can't work effectively in German, and they can't or won't work effectively in English.  That's it.  They're the company, you're the outsider here, so it's your job (literally) to adapt or leave.

There is a 4th option which is to complain to management that they're supposed to be an international company but they only speak German, but that's not likely to go particularly well unless you have some supporting documentation like an employee handbook or something to point to.  I would go this route only as an absolute last resort if the other 3 choices really don't work.

Comment: Fifth option: Accept that you aren't going to be really good really fast, and settle for being able to struggle along and improve over time.

Comment: "Get really good at German, really fast." that's not really an option. Getting to C1 is estimated by the Goethe institue to take 600-750 hours of studying (from fluent English), which realistically takes years.

Comment: I would be going with (3) on this situation.

Comment: @njzk2 That depends on what level of ‘Really good’ you need, and how good you are at languages. True C1 is likely overkill for work unless you’re interacting with customers, it’s quite often good enough to get to B1 or B2 and then specialize in the correct jargon for your job beyond that instead of going for true C1 or C2 proficiency, and it will quite often take far less time even if you’re especially bad with languages.

Comment: I'm not sure what "C1" means, but I would say "daily conversation + business-specific jargon" is sufficient for working in a second language.  When I had my experience in Japanese, I could do daily conversation but not business jargon, and my company had a well-known and well-documented English-speaking policy that I could point to if issues arose, which OP may not have the benefit of.  I could probably have managed to work in Japanese if I was required to, but the English-speaking policy at the company encouraged me not to try.

Comment: @Ertai87 B2, C1 etc refers to the language level according to the Common European Framework of Reference for Languages (CEFR).

Comment: @njzk2 C1 means "Can understand a wide range of demanding, longer texts, and recognise implicit meaning. Can express him/herself fluently and spontaneously without much obvious searching for expressions. Can use language flexibly and effectively for social, academic and professional purposes. Can produce clear, well-structured, detailed text on complex subjects, showing controlled use of organisational patterns, connectors and cohesive devices.". That's definitely more than the minimum requirement for working in an office environment.

Comment: @Voo at least B2 to be able to hold complex conversation about detailed points, not to mention the jargon. That's still at least half the time to C1, more like 75%, still in the range of several years, unless you study several hours every day.

Comment: @njzk2 I'd say B2 is where it's comfortable for both speakers to work. B1 is generally fine for business talk, but it'll take longer and be more exhausting for all participants (yes also the listeners). In my experience you don't really learn the language from language courses but from using it every day. It might take you several years if you just go to language courses several times a week, but if you speak German at work and with friends I've seen quite a few people get to B2 in about a year.

Comment: @Voo that's exactly my point: a colleague saying "she must learn German", and other trying to push assignment in German in order to encourage this is pointless: it'll be months at best before any progress is visible

Comment: @njzk2 Well you have to start sooner or later and sooner is definitely better. Procrastinating isn't going to help. And you absolutely see progress much sooner than after several months. I was quite involved with exchange students and the expat community after I came back from the US and the progress people make if they decide to speak solely German is impressive. The problem children were always the ones that spoke English at work and spent most of their time with other expats, even if they went to 4-5 language courses a week.

Comment: For a point of reference, it took me (at age 44) 3-4 months of radio audio courses plus one full year of 3 day a week, 3 hrs a day classes plus homework to get to about B2/C1. I got 3 job offers after interviews in german and worked as a software developer deaign with business and customers exclusively in German for 2 years. I am a musician and a programmer, both of which might help a lot, I don't know. It was twice as long as I had estimated.

Comment: @njzk2: For what it's worth, I learned German by full immersion, explicitly asking people to not speak English to me. After a month, I could understand most of what people told me, provided they spoke slowly and without any crazy accent. After 2 months, I could work and get myself understood. It surely wasn't "Get really good at German, really fast.", but more of "Get good enough at German, fast enough". After many years in Germany, I still have much to learn, but the human brain can learn really fast if there's no other alternative.

Answer (score 12):

I work in Austria and have lots of colleagues who moved here from from different countries. I’m a native Austrian. We are a small branch of a big US company. It’s understood that English is the company language and all our documentation and most written communication is in English.

If I talk or write directly to German-speaking colleagues or have a meeting with German-speaking colleagues I’ll use German. But the moment someone who doesn’t speak German joins we usually default to English immediately.

Occasionally we’ll inquire (in a friendly way) how somebody’s German learning is progressing and if they are okay with having the meeting or conversation in German. Some replies I’ve heard: “Okay, but I’ll interrupt if I don’t understand”; “I can understand just fine, but I’ll reply in English”; “Let’s use English for the technical stuff”; “No, please stick with English”.

We’ve had German conversations/meetings where people joined without us realizing and they gently interrupted with a “sorry guys, can we please switch to English?”.

In my opinion this is the way it should be done and the only way a conversation, meeting or presentation can actually work. You can’t just force somebody to speak or understand a foreign language they have insufficient knowledge or skill in.

If you start a business conversation in English and they reply in German and completely ignore that you don’t understand every second word (or even want you to reply in German), how do they expect that to work?!

Comment: Have to disagree. This is _a_ way it can be done, and it is certainly the path of least resistance, but you're doing your foreign colleagues a disservice in the big picture. Unless they they have a lot of social contacts with whom they speak German, they'll never properly learn the language this way. Language courses are only good as a supplement and to iron out mistakes, but they're almost useless for getting comfortable with using the language in everyday settings.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: For business conversations you can’t just force people who barely know the language headfirst into it (at least not if you want to transfer information or have  meaningful discussion). For small talk at the coffee machine it’s a different matter. Though I still think the foreign person should have a say in it and shouldn’t feel left out.

Comment: This is a good answer and how I believe the situation should be treated.

@leftaroundabout that choice belongs only to the language learner. It is not right for me to impose a situation in which I'm speaking my native language which I know you struggle with, UNLESS that was explicitly agreed beforehand. This is a business context, not a language-learning center.

Comment: @GustavoPuma you got it backwards. By leaving it up to the language learner, you're in the long run putting _more_ pressure on their shoulders. Of course they will feel anxious and afraid to make mistakes, and to take up everybody's time with stammering – but this is an inevitable stage if they're ever going to use the language at all in business. By leaving it up to the learner, you're putting all responsibility on them to get over this hurdle. Whereas by forcing them to use German, you acknowledge that the stammering is “good enough for you” and that you're willing to bear with it.

Comment: (Of course, that's not to say you should start right on the first day with a newcomer who hasn't even had a chance to learn understanding. Start by probing their skills at the coffee machine, but then expand from there as quickly as possible.)

Comment: While this provides a good analogous situation based on your own experience, it doesn't really explain what the question author should do to convince their coworkers to do this as well.

Answer (score 9):

Do the presentation in English.

If someone asks you about it, or complains, or says something in German, just tell them you don't speak German.

As long as your contract doesn't say that you're supposed to speak German, and as long as you haven't misled anyone about your abilities, you should be fine*.

To be clear: you did nothing wrong, and it is the company's decision to hire non German speakers. Good for you that you're taking classes, but again, and especially as the company doesn't support you, there's no obligation (of means or result) on your part.

Your colleagues have to accept to speak English, or complain higher up - but certainly not to you. This way they'll get a clarification about what is the working language of the company.

---

*If you're on probation, that might be the point where the company realizes it made a mistake, decides to hire German speakers from now one, and ends your contract. If you're not on probation, you should be fine.

Comment: -1 - this is bad advice. German is an official language in Germany, and English is not - there's an implicit expectation that you learn German with every job, unless it's explicitly stated in the contract. "She's trying, but struggling, and has to switch to English from time to time when she doesn't know the German version of a word" will be met with much more enthusiasm from colleagues than "She doesn't even try".

Comment: @GuntramBlohm It's not some random colleagues job to criticize OPs use of language though (and them saying 'she has to learn German' if/when OPs contract doesn't require it seems xenophobic). OP is a bit vague on who demands what here, but if it's not someone who actually has the authority to do so, it's very questionable behavior on their part.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm "there's an implicit expectation that you learn German with every job, unless it's explicitly stated in the contract." not quite. There's no expectation that you'll speak German _at all_, unless it's explicitly stated in the contract. Whether that's the case or not should be made obvious by the recruiter and interviewers. (source: having worked several jobs in Germany, none of which carried the expectation that I would ever speak German)

Comment: @GuntramBlohm to add to this: this company hired someone, fully knowing that that person didn't know German, and that learning that language can take years, if it happens at all. The company is not in a position to ask the OP to learn German now. It will take months or years, and meanwhile everyone else will have demonstrated that they speak English anyway, as the company is international.

Comment: This. >>The company does not support language learning,  You don't get it both ways.  If you enforce a new employee having a skill that's not a requirement at interview, or to complete the job, then you train the employee or support their own training.  If you don't do that you don't enforce the skill.

Comment: @njzk2: "There's no expectation that you'll speak German at all, unless it's explicitly stated in the contract"

Actually, this varies from place to place.

A statement like "there's no expectation [...] at all, unless it's explicitly stated in the contract" is true in the US for example, but not everywhere. Especially in countries like England and France, people are very chauvinistic. There, you're expected to conform (i.e. learn the language) unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: If you go somewhere for a longer period, then you learn the language! Period! Refusing that by giving a presentation in another language is pure provocation and a huge insult!

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, “German is an official language in Germany”, this is irrelevant to how the company operates internally. This attitude is a reason for why many German companies have a hard time attracting international talent.

Comment: @Dominique, so if I ever came to Belgium I should only speak German, and never English, because German is one of the official languages and English is not?

Comment: @CarstenS: if you would behave like this in front of me, I would feel delighted having a good opportunity to practice the beautiful language of Goethe and Schiller :-) But lots of other Belgian people wouldn't agree because most people in Belgium don't know German: first they learn Dutch, then French, then English and then German, or they start with French, after a very short period of Dutch they switch to English and German is again the fourth choice. Only in the German-speaking part of Belgium, your system would work. But as far as I'm concerned, you're very welcome :-)

Comment: @Dominique, I just wanted to point out that speaking English would sometimes be pragmatically the best option. And that is while I am nevertheless sad that the French that I learned at school does not enable me to actually speak French.

Comment: @Dominique Please read my original post carefully again. As much as I agree that one should speak the language of the country they live in, I feel it is not relevant to my situation. The company hired me being aware of my lack of German skills, yet now they demand to speak German even though it is not what we agreed upon. Furthermore, I am learning German in my own time without any support from the company.

Comment: @Dominique So my problem is the pressure I receive from them and the unfair treatment because of it, which blocks me to do a good and efficient job. Not to mention the level of German skills I need for my job is vastly different compared to going to the supermarket or other easy, everyday tasks.

Comment: @CarstenS: that's a really poor thing to say, especially against a Belgian, and especially against a Flemish: I have done a big effort learning first Dutch (my mother tongue), then German, then French and English only came when I was sixteen years old (in my twenties I managed to add Spanish to the list, too). If people come to my country and refuse to do any effort, that makes me furious. Now obviously, you might come to Belgium and speak English, most people would help you, but at least a small effort will be asked for adopting the regional language.

Comment: @user138043: I have written two things: in a comment on this answer I have said that you should not limit yourself to English, you should try to learn German (which you already are doing). I have also written an answer, where I give you some advise on how you can improve yourself learning German.

Comment: @user138043 100% with you. Even if you learn German (congratulation on that, by the way!), it's not reasonable to put pressure on you to do presentations in German before you are ready to do so.

Comment: @Dominique Good for you. Congratulation. Not relevant to anyone else's situation, and in particular not relevant to the OP's situation.

Comment: @tim it is not "xenophobic". It is just people feeling more comfortable doing their everyday job in their native language. Their contracts also do not say that they have to speak English. So it would be perfectly valid for one of them to express the concern that he is not comfortable in English and that switching to English also hurts his productivity. And it would be perfectly reasonable for the team/the managers to try to find a solution that works for everyone **without** throwing words like "xenophobic" around.

Comment: @wimi "Their contracts also do not say that they have to speak English" you don't know that. And that seems contradictory with the fact that the OP was hired by a company that knew she wasn't fluent in German.

Comment: @njzk2 I am in Germany and I have never seen a contract in which the language of the work is specified. I would guess that in most cases like OP's, no employee has a mention of language in the contract. And many companies have started to become international only recently, so they still have many employees that have been there for 20 or 30 years and have been speaking German all that time. Internationalization is a good goal, and required to find talent, but calling long-time employees "xenophobic" is not the way to do it.

Comment: @wimi I agree, it's too much. There are 2 things here: one is that the supervisor behaved, according to the OP's description, inappropriately. The second is that there is a conflict in what 2 employees are expecting from their workplace. It's presumably the fault of neither, as both, if acting in good faith, have been led to believe that the working language would be the one they speak. This needs to be resolved by the company, considering what sort of promises (oral or written) were made to the employees

Comment: @njzk2 Exactly! I think you truly understood my situation. I also believe my colleagues are not the ones mistaken here. I think the company is not yet international (at least from the language perspective), yet it is advertised as one, eventually causing conflict between the employees.

Answer (score 9):

I feel like nobody has answered the question you asked in your headline:

> How can I make the people at my company understand that learning a spoken and written language takes time?

I will assume they *do* understand. If they come from Germany, either former eastern or western, or immigrated like you, they alread had to learn foreign languages and it took them *years*.

But they are completely in the dark about your progress, because they do not sit in class with you, as they did with their former classmates in school.

So instead of you learning the language being some secret, make it obvious. Make it public.

For a start, say something like

> Hey boss, at my current level of language learning, we have lessons on asking for the way to the train station. I'm not yet able to hold a presentation on the economic viability of fooing widgets in the Bar industry in German, that is way over my head. The skills I need for this are covered in B1. I am currently working on A2 and I expect to be on B1 level maybe next March.

As always in business, don't leave it at a straight "I can't", offer up solutions for this problem yourself:

> I can prepare this in English, or if you have another person in mind to present, I can help them gathering all the material for the presentation.

So my advice is, let them *know* where you stand. Let them know at what level you are at, so they know that what they asked is ridiculous. If you told people your German class last week had you learn about how to ask for directions to the restroom, people in the room will know what your boss asks of you is too much and will support you if you speak up. But if they don't know... they have no chance to do so, and you are on your own.

That said, maybe you can talk to your boss about your situation. You said you were promised more meetings with the (English speaking) developers in the interview. If that is not the case, have a talk with your boss about it.

Comment: Thank you! I scheduled a call with my manager to talk about my concerns in regards to our agreement in the past, as well as to discuss that if their expectations have changed for some reason, I would prefer to have certain milestones set for me to measure my progress. Throwing me 'in the deep water' with a presentation which at this point, I was not able to handle, given that it was requested two days before the presentation was planned to happen is I believe not a way to go about this.

Answer (score 8):

> then someone else spoke up and said 'She has to learn German'.

If this is not what you were told when you were hired, you may want to have a private talk with that person. But the key is to do this privately, you won't have a chance if you have to make your argument against more than one person at a time.

Also if you have documentary evidence that you would not be required to conduct business in German, either in your offer letter, or in your contract, or in the original job posting, or if an original timeline was agreed upon for learning German, that would also strengthen your argument and would make it much more bulletproof.

But even if you don't have that proof, you may still want to consult with a German employment lawyer. After all, if nothing was mentioned, and if you've conducted business in English until now. Maybe there is a legal argument in your favor. I don't know.

> Now they asked me to do a presentation in German, which frustrates me
>
> and I don't know what to do.

Here is one thing you could do:

Prepare the presentation in your native language or in English, [translate](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) it to German, and then have a native speaking German coworker/friend/tutor correct it for you.

Make sure to include a number of interesting diagrams and visual elements to your slides. Keep the presentation as short and as concise as possible. Then memorize the presentation using [spaced repetition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3I17n4OyNE) and a tool like [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). And then practice that presentation in front of your friend/tutor.

I've known some foreigners that have memorized their favorite American movies verbatim before they could even understand the English language. So if this is possible in English, I'm pretty sure this is possible in German as well. It's just a question of preparation and time.

In addition to that, try anticipating some of the questions they might ask you, and prepare some answers to those questions. Also, prepare some generic answers as well in case you don't know the answer, or in case you need to get back to them later after the meeting.

Comment: I have been in Germany more than 30 years and I still get my colleagues to correct my presentations. In return I correct their English, which is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have thoroughly explored the pragmatic and contractual side of things, and also emphasized the important effect of immersion. I would therefore like to elaborate on other, less discussed, but potentially meaningful aspects.

**Linguistic aspect:**

During my attempts to speak German with German-speaking people, I came to the realization that it's very easy for learners (up to upper-intermediate level) to produce speech that German speakers cannot properly decipher. To offer a scientifically incorrect, but illustrative example:

> In the context of recent developments in the market, it's very
> important that we update our strategy by [ *undecipherable* ] our R&D
> activities. Correspondingly, our analysts have observed that our
> competitors also have taken the measure to [ *undecipherable* ] assets in
> this regard.

The listener will get that the discussed topic carries huge importance, but they are unable to arrive to any conclusion regarding the objective. Is it to invest more? Or is it to dial spending down?

I have observed German speakers *wince and squint* in painful frustration when they had the task of figuring out what I tried to say.

I find your supervisor's willingness to expose your team to such effects perplexing.

**Social effect:**

I have observed that when I speak broken German, such German-speakers who don't know me from other contexts, and have to evaluate my person solely on the given conversation, tend to significantly underestimate my cognitive abilities. Soon they appear to take me no more seriously than some child. I have found that the only quick remedy to this is switching to English.

I would be concerned whether a similar effect could occur in your case, thanks to the supervisor's insistence on you using German. I would also contemplate whether he is aware of such effects, and what he thinks about 1. how this influences others' perception of you, and 2. how this influences your career within the company.

**Cultural factors:**

1.

From anecdotal accounts by various German-learning-related Youtube contributors, I have learned that in non-work context, foreign learners of the German language can regularly experience a frustration opposite to yours. Namely, when someone tries to practice their German skills with natives in public environments, like entering into ad-hoc dialogue on the street, during shopping, or similar, even when the learner initiated the dialogue in German, natives will often switch to and maintain the conversation in English.

To me, this illustrates that they can be very much sensitive to people's struggle with the difficulty of the German language. (Or alternatively, that they don't want to be subjected to the linguistic challenges discussed above...)

2.

Also mainly from similar sources as above, I have learned about a significant cultural aspect in German society. It's about a collective awareness about individuals' role in the collective well-being. This kind of thing will result in personal boundaries being addressed differently from what individuals got used to in some other cultures. What I mean:

In Germany, it is a common experience that people living in a neighbourhood keep an eye on each other's conduct, and go as far as correcting each other's actions when someone does something against the common good, the generally agreed guidelines of conduct. This can manifest itself in calling you out for not respecting limitations imposed by the "house rules", in calling you out for not separating properly your recyclable waste, or causing discomfort to others unintentionally, typically in lack of self-awareness, by, say, blocking their transit on a narrow stretch of a pavement.

The intent here is less to do with trespassing your boundaries, but rather, to achieve and maintain a more harmonic coexistence — even at the cost of minor confrontations. (Out of necessity, this harmony is expected to be achieved primarily in the near future (say, literally, from tomorrow on), as in the present a minor sacrifice was made, in the form of the confrontation itself.)

During this practice, it appears to me, Germans may grant themselves (and each other) the right to — to some extent — arrive at conclusions and make decisions ***on your behalf*** — and expect you to adopt them —, as long as it is percieved to serve the common harmony.

I guess such a pattern is not entirely foreign in other cultures either; the difference is how well it's adopted in Germany. This I believe is due to how it is taken constructively, and is acknowledged as a legitim dynamic of shaping — and doing a positive contribution to — a harmonic collective existence.

Now, for fairness' sake, it's worth acknowledging that such a dynamic is not free from the potential to abuse, and that some individuals may develop insufferable behaviours in this context.

I believe it would be pretty meaningful to figure out whether your supervisor is relying on this cultural pattern out of a benevolent motivation, or whether he is abusing it.

**Counting on diversity:**

Even with its distinctive culture, Germany — obviously — is not a hermetically sealed environment, and, obviously, a lot of cultural exchange is taking place, resulting in a variety of stances and nuances in evaluating situations, accross individuals.

You even mentioned that some colleagues are indeed way more empathic about the challenge you face than your supervisor. This illustrates that your company is very likely capable of accommodating you with as much sensitivity and common sense as you expect, but perhaps it is your supervisor who grants an unreasonably low weight to empathic considerations.

These insights seem to open up another alternative: if your supervisor wouldn't budge in accepting you carrying out critically important communication in English, you could still contemplate opportunities for a transfer within the same company, and thus ending up working with a different supervisor, or even, in a different type of hierarchy.

Comment: "natives will often switch to and maintain the conversation in English." definitely hasn't been my experience, though

Comment: finding a different supervisor sounds like a good idea, especially given the described attitude of the current one

Answer (score 4):

I guess this presentation you are asked to do is not for clients but rather an internal presentation for your colleagues. So my take on it is that the main/only reason they are making you do this presentation is for your educational benefit. I don't think they are expecting a flawless presentation or even something that could be presented to a client.

So just do your best, don't fret too much over it and everything probably will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

There is one information missing. And I think a crucial one:

How do they speak in German when you are around?

1. Are they talking fast and quite complex sentences as all around are German?

   Then it is your time to stand up for yourself and clearly but respectfully say them that this does not work for you both personally (it is frustrating and infuriating) and professionally (you have no clue what talk about). It may be time to raise the issue to your boss or boss's boss and HR. Clearly state you are doing your best to accommodate and they ignore that.
2. They talk slower, clearer and using simpler language.

   From my experience only actually-parenting parents and those-who-worked-with-small-kids can do that. Others fall to their "native" language easily and need to train themselves to keep it simple. You can remind them of your lack of native-German skill. You can ask "Entschulidgen Sie mir bitte, was ist 'The Phrase You Cannot decipher'?"

You can also defend yourself by "Yes, I need to learn German. But I also need to understand you to work here. Thank you." If you defend yourself this way in German, points for you.

Do not demand their help. Explain them why they benefit from helping you. If it doesn't work, your life is too short for such a team.

Comment: I don't know about you, but if I have to a/ simplify my language b/ slow down c/ train kids, all that while trying to communication complex work-related concepts, my productivity drops very fast.

Comment: @njzk2 That is the compromise. Your simpler vocabulary and/or slower pace is the price for the foreigner being able to understand you a bit more. Other option, ruled by "She has to learn German", is simple: All use the language everyone is efficient with.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. You ask "how can I make them understand that learning a new language takes a lot of time?". But they know that.

Everyone going to school in West Germany late enough so that they are in their early sixties now has had six years education in English, but more likely nine years. Someone older, 64, 65, or older, might not. The people in your company DO speak English. Visiting Germany with friends, they never had the slightest problem being understood in English, as long as you know to speak your best, accent free, mumbling free, slow, English. The only exception is when someone is very old (went to school before English lessons for everyone), or doesn't *want* to understand English. I've worked with plenty of English speaking people in Germany, either from English speaking company, or from non-German country when their English was better than their German, without problems.

What these people however have is a severe attitude problem. The person saying "She has to learn German" just doesn't like you, wants to show their power, is a sexist pig, whatever the reason. Not speaking English is not the reason. Do your presentation in English. It will be better understood than you trying to do the presentation in German. (Yes, you need to be quite good in German to reach the point where Germans understand your German better than your English). If there are complaints, ask if they understand English. If they answer "you should learn German", ask again if they understand English.

For a comparison, at 18 I *had* to read maths texts in English at university, no way round it. Had an English teacher at school at 16 who didn't speak German, and another (German native) English teacher who flatly refused to speak German in the classroom at 17. And people trying to learn German in Germany regularly complain that as soon as they open their mouth, people reply in English!

Comment: "What these people however have is a severe attitude problem." That seems harsh. Why do you assume everyone in the company is actually been through a (West)German school system? We have plenty of people bad at english and excellent at Russian or Arabic. If the smallest common denominator in that company is spoken German, then it seems pretty arrogant to call that an "attitude problem" of those involved.

Comment: @nvoigt in which case maybe the company should have thought of that earlier, and hire only German-speaking employees.

Comment: what the hell is "accent free" English?

Comment: @njzk2 So your solution is that the OP should be fired? Does not seem very constructive either.

Comment: @Phil Go to Birmingham and if you don't understand them, that's because of the accent :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 UK or Alabama? ;)

Comment: Also -1 for the assumption that these people have an attitude problem.  The highest-rated answer (currently) provides a much more likely, much less assumptive reason why the coworkers might require OP to speak in German.  Not that they're right to be doing so, but simply assuming the coworkers are "sexist pig[s]" because they require OP to speak German is a bit much.

Comment: The assumption that everyone below 65 will speak good enough English to follow a presentation in English is also hilariously optimistic (also you are aware that Germany is more  than just West Germany, right? English wasn't a mandatory subject in the DDR): Looking for studies on the topic (e.g. the Eurobarometer 2012) shows about 56% of Germans who have English proficiency. And that proficiency will vary wildly.

Comment: "And people trying to learn German in Germany regularly complain that as soon as they open their mouth, people reply in English" There's just the possibility that this is why one coworker reminded the other one to speak German with OP... ("She has to learn German" sounds to me like an almost literal translation of what could be in German a blunt and direct, but in no way antagonistic [neither to OP nor to the English speaking coworker] reminder)

Comment: @Voo if it's hilariously optimistic that people with years of schooling can't understand English well enough to follow a presentation, why is it not even more ludicrous to expect a non-German speaker to give the presentation, a massively more difficult task?

Comment: @David That's just pointing to research that shows that the underlying assumption in this post is simply wrong, no more no less. (If you're wondering why visiting friends in a probably big city talking to people in the hospitality business had a very easy time with English.. by that argument everyone in Italy speaks perfect German as well - classic selection bias)

Comment: -1. Colleagues showing OP some tough love aren't "sexist pigs". Your proposal achieves nothing, and will leave OP with the exact same problem in a few years.

Comment: @nvoigt either the company want to work in English, and then should enforce it, or, the company wants to work in German, and the OP is not ready for that at the moment. As there is no fault on the side of the OP, the company can try to negotiate an agreement for the OP to leave, with a good recommendation, and enough time and money to find another job.

Comment: @EricDuminil no love to be found there, tough or otherwise. Only public shaming and bullying. Don't forget that this is coming from her supervisor, without leaving any room for discussion.

Comment: @njzk2: I've learned 3 foreign languages with the immersion approach, including German. Should I call back my roommates & colleagues to tell them they were sexist pigs, and that they shouldn't have bullied me?

Comment: @EricDuminil presumably that was your choice to go with this approach. Good for you. It doesn't mean the OP has to receive this sort of attitude from her supervisor. There's a big difference between: "Hey folks, I'm trying to learn German ASAP, please only speak German to me", and "Hey, I've decided you'll learn German _now_, during this meeting, and I don't care if you disagree, or miss half of what is said in the meeting, because I'm the boss, hahaha"

Comment: @njzk2: Presumably OP decided to go to Germany, and sign a contract written in German.

Comment: @EricDuminil what's your point? (also, not necessarily) (and again, none of that would mean the OP has to receive this sort of attitude from her supervisor)

Comment: Downvoted. "Sexist pigs"? What does sexism have to do with any of this?

Answer (score 2):

Willkommen in Deutschland!

This is a known problem that I faced myself years ago at the beginning. I will try to explain why it is so and what did I do to overcome it.

What I identified as possible reasons:

1. **It's a cultural thing.** German is a very precise language. As
   you've already probably noticed, they have a word for everything.
   From my experience, a lot of them don't understand something out of
   context, but need exact wording. They are not dumb or something,
   it's their language that makes them this way. Even if you speak in
   another language, they can't switch their mindset easily to
   understand out of context and need exact wordings. Your native
   language / language that you use the most partially defines how you
   think. Your superior may not have a good enough grasp of English to
   understand what you mean and he has to make decisions and has to
   fully understand what is happening (imagine that you switch sides).
2. **Germans are bad at English.** Yes, they are. They speak and
   understand it, but I rarely met one that has a fluent and a good
   command of the language. Just go over the border to Netherlands and
   you can speak English to literally anyone. An incredible difference. One of the reasons is that they don't use it often as they don't need it. In Germany, everything is in German, including TV broadcast.
3. **Arrogance.** As some of the commentators in this topic, a lot of
   them are just purely arrogant. It's a superiority complex. You just
   have to live with it if you want to live in Germany. And this is not exclusive to Germany.

What I did and what I would like to suggest you is that you write your presentation in English, but speak in German. It doesn't matter that you don't know the exact article or conjugate a verb wrong or make a wrong declension...just do your best. That's why you have everything written down in the language that you know well. Don't be afraid to ask them to speak slowly or to translate or tell you in simpler terms what they said and you didn't understand. Don't be afraid to use an English word instead of a German one if you don't know it (Denglish), that's ok. Don't be afraid to tell them to speak in *Hochdeutsch* if they speak Bavarian or another dialect that is not official, because official German dialect in Germany is Hochdeutsch. They know that you don't know, always have that in mind.

If they are still belonging to the third group (arrogant) and don't want to help you, although they know your problem and still they employed you and they know you learn on your expense in your free time, then leave! Or ask for transfer to another department if the company is big enough. State your reasons to HR exactly as you wrote it here.

Germany is a big place and there are a lot of (truly international) companies that are very friendly and will value your effort. Don't get bogged down because of these specific bunch. Most of the Germans I met are normal and friendly and flexible, especially the younger generation.

I want to also mention that this problem is not Germany specific only. You'll find it anywhere in the world, especially in the bigger countries where their language is enough for their private and business life and, what I also noticed, that have TV broadcast synchronized in their language.

Answer (score 1):

First, you make sure you have enough time for giving your presentation, because you will need more time to give the presentation as you struggle with the language.

Then you start:

Guten Mittag.
Ich. Möchte. Ihren. Gerne. Was. Erzählen. Uber. Meine. Arbeit.
Das. Werde. Gans. Lange. Dauern. Weil. Ich. Noch. Nicht. So. Gut. Deutsch. Rede.
Ich. Bitte. Sie. Allen. Auch. So. Langsam. Mit. Mir. Zu. Reden.
...
(Please don't kill me if I've made some errors, it's been a while that I've written German)

At first, this is pure nerve-wrecking: talking so slowly, with an extra space between each and every word, is very frustrating, but you have two advantages:

- Talking that slowly gives you the opportunity to think about your words while you are pronouncing them. You'll make far less mistakes.
- When other people speak that slowly to you (which is exactly what you are asking them to do), you have a far better chance to understand what they are saying, which will improve your knowledge of the German language.

This gives you an opportunity to show that you are actually learning German and it gives you a way to improve you German knowledge, once your colleagues agree to use this way of communicating towards you.

Ich wünsche Sie vielen Glück :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess your suggestion, if put into action, could appear as mocking the audience and could backfire heavily from a professional POV. This is not in the interest of the OP.

Comment: I have been a teamleader and a new colleague came to my department, she was Mexican. She tried to speak Dutch so when I talked to her, I did it exactly the way I described here, and she was glad that somebody did so much effort for helping her.

Comment: OK, but that was a suggestion *from a teamleader*, not your colleague initiative. The OP seems to have no one in the team supporting her, or at least she doesn't feel supported, so there is probably already a communication issue at play. Such an approach could be OK, IMO, only if agreed upon in advance with her manager or supervisor, otherwise it's very risky.

Comment: Sounds like it's going to be a really efficient and productive presentation :)

Comment: @njzk2: Exactly: instead of twenty minutes, the presentation might take thirty. Who cares? This is not an empty question, but a very important one: we are dealing with a colleague, trying her best to do something, which takes more time. If people have a problem with that, they are not helpful towards her and she should not care about those people. However the colleagues who are willing to help her, won't mind for those extra ten minutes. ... and there's the catch: who is the majority? The frustrated one? Quit your job. The nice ones? Stay there and continue doing your best.

Comment: @Dominique If that's the case, it should have been clear from the start in the interview process. Hire someone who doesn't have a skill that you expect them to have is a big mistake, and that mistake is for the company to fix, not the OP. Also, the flippant "She has to learn German" is still not, in my view, being "helpful towards her"

Comment: @Dominique this is a very concrete situation, not a hypothetical about whether people should learn the local language and try to integrate. The OP was hired, and is legitimate in having expectations: the hiring process was in English, and apparently it was clear the work was to be expected to be conducted in English. Now she is facing a different situation, and just "adapt or quit" is not right. She did nothing wrong, no reason to face consequences for someone else's mistake. It is possible that the supervisor also has legitimate expectations to work in German, ...

Comment: ... but in that case strong-arming the OP into an uncomfortable situation on the spot is not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be the only European answering here, but They are correct. **You have to learn German**, if you should decide to stay there.

When we tell you that you have to learn a language it is so that you can properly function in society. This is in no way meant to be an insult, but is merely stating a factual observation. Learning a language will bring you in closer to the people and will remove any isolation barriers that may exist. It will also be the first step in staying out of poverty because you will be able to have more access to resources which may not be viable if you don't know the language.

**The pressure to learn a language is healthy** as you are feeling a sense of the need to survive in a foreign environment and it shouldn't be considered negative.

That being said, learning a language is hard - They know this. Try learning the language and speaking it with them. **Small phrases and motivation goes a VERY long way.**

**Start the day be greeting everyone in German**, and trying to use it as much as possible. order food (drinks) in German when you are with the company. Show that you have a command of the language.

Comment: While this might be good advice in general, it won't help OP in this particular situation. What to do about meetings held in German that she cannot follow? What to do about the presentation? What are your thoughts on that? Just suck it up?

Comment: You're certainly not the only European here: I'm even a Belgian, who speaks Dutch, French **and** German, which also explains my upvote :-)

Comment: I have lived in Belgium for a very small time and don't know French or Dutch ) I would record the conversation or ask someone to paraphrase the meeting.  This uncomfortability is healthy to learning the language and you can take words from that meeting and learn.

There could be some help, but she is correctfully being told to learn the language .

Answer (score -2):

If it's an international company, you can go with the "inclusion" argument. Mention that you "don't feel included", or that you "feel excluded". These keywords frame the issue as a diversity & inclusion topic which then should get treated very sensitively, latest by HR. You can also use the keyword "pressured" or "stressed" which should also signal it's a serious issue.

This obviously assumes there was no expectation of learning German when you joined (which should have been mentioned in the job description). If the job description was in English and there was no mention of German skills I think you'd be in the right.

If German skill was mentioned, then treat it as you'd treat any other skill - discuss the progress with your manager, set expectations and ask them to create a develop plan for you. Then regularly review the progress and plan with your manager. If it's an important skill for your job that was part of your job description, it's your managers' responsibility to help you develop it.

Comment: I've worked with Germans who had taken the time to learn very good English and, I assume you that that approach would not have impressed them. I can imagine one of them saying, "If you don't feel included here, maybe this isn't the job for you".

Comment: @SimonCrase The OP has also taken the time to learn good English, apparently. So, no reason to feel impressed by this. And "maybe this isn't the job for you" is bullying at best, and definitely not a cause for getting the OP fired of their job* (*assuming that this happens in one of the German speaking countries, w.r.t. to employment laws, and that the OPs contract mentions working in English, or at least does not mention having to work in German.)

Comment: @njzk2 "The OP has also taken the time to learn good English" I don't disagree, althouh German would be more useful in Germany. However when I said that my German colleagues were "very good", I actually meant "flawless"; one of them irritated his colleagues by picking up grammatical mistakes made be native speakers (it is very difficult for a foreigner to make the right mistakes to pass as a native speaker).
My sympathies are with the lady who said, "She has to learn German". It's a very long shot to call that bullying; it sounds more like "tough love" to me.

Comment: @SimonCrase definitely not tough love. Absolutely bullying. Learning takes time, results don't show immediately, so what happens in between? Will that lady monitor the OP's progress? Chastise when it doesn't go fast enough? Keep repeating that "she has to learn" every time the OP speaks English? Or do you really think that the OP will say: "I'm learning", and that lady will leave it at that, and not bring it up for the next couple of years?

Comment: @njzk2 There was a time when some English and Americans insisted that "the natives" speak English. I'm puzzled by this attitude amongst people whose native language isn't English. Forty years ago I  ran into a German lady who was aggrieved that the natives of one Pacific island spoke Tok Pijin rather than English; more recently I met a Malaysian gentlemen who was upset that the Japanese spoke their own language. Maybe they had both invested time learning English because they perceived it to be "international", and expected other to do the same. When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Comment: @SimonCrase That is the sensible (and culturally-correct) thing to do when approaching a native in their environment, but here we are speaking of a company with strong international connections. No shopkeeper would be offended by a lady trying to buy, say, bread and milk using a broken German. If it took double time, well, meh, it would create some empathy due to the effort. But in a professional framework you are supposed to deliver at the level of your expertise and if you can't do that that could be viewed as a professional failure....

Comment: @SimonCrase ...  Unless there is a clear understanding on both parts that she won't be penalized for doing a less-than-adequate job as long as she shows improvement in her language skills, then she is not treated fairly.

Comment: @SimonCrase I'm not asking Germans to speak English. But I would ask the employees of a company where the working language is whatever to speak that language.

Comment: @njzk2 Given that we have no indication that the working language of the German company is *not* German, you are asking the OP to speak German.

Comment: @nvoigt the OP was hired by a company that knew she wasn't fluent in German. The interviews were conducted in English, and the OP was transparent about here fluency level. If despite that the working language of the company is German, that's a big problem